# MySQL Split Time Ranges into Smaller Chunks

Tags: php, mysql, time

I've recently been tasked with finishing a PHP/MySQL web app when the developer quit last week. I'm no MySQL expert, so I apologize if this is an intensely simple question. I've searched SO for the better part of two days trying to find a relatively easy solution to my problem, which is as follows.

Problem in a Nutshell:
I have a MySQL table full of start and end datetime (GMT -5) & UNIX Timestamp values covering durations of irregular length and need to break/split/divide them into more-regular time chunks (5 minutes). I'm not after a count of row entries per time chunk/bucket/period, if that makes any sense.

Data Example:

```
started, ended, started_UNIX, ended_UNIX  
2010-10-25 15:12:33, 2010-10-25 15:47:09, 1288033953, 1288036029
```

What I'm hoping to get:

```
2010-10-25 15:12:33, 2010-10-25 15:15:00, 1288033953, 1288037700  
2010-10-25 15:15:00, 2010-10-25 15:20:00, 1288037700, 1288038000  
2010-10-25 15:20:00, 2010-10-25 15:25:00, 1288038000, 1288038300  
2010-10-25 15:25:00, 2010-10-25 15:30:00, 1288038300, 1288038600  
2010-10-25 15:30:00, 2010-10-25 15:35:00, 1288038600, 1288038900  
2010-10-25 15:35:00, 2010-10-25 15:40:00, 1288038900, 1288039200  
2010-10-25 15:40:00, 2010-10-25 15:45:00, 1288039200, 1288039500  
2010-10-25 15:45:00, 2010-10-25 15:47:09, 1288039500, 1288039629
```

If you're interested, here's the quick & dirty on the app and why I need the data:
App overview: The application receives very simple POST requests generated by a basic sensor device when its input pins go to ground, which submits an INSERT query to the database where MySQL records a timestamp (as started). When the input pins return from a grounded state, the device submits a different POST request, which causes the PHP app to submit an UPDATE query, where a modification time timestamp is inserted (as ended).

My employer recently changed the periodic reporting unit of measure from *Seconds "On" Per Day* to *Seconds "On" Per 5 Minute Interval*. I had formulated what I thought would be a workable solution, but when I looked at it on paper, it looked like Rube Goldberg's nightmare constructed in MySQL, so that was out.

Any suggestions as to how to break these spans into 5 minute blocks? Keeping it all in MySQL would be my preference, though I'll take **any** suggestions. Thank you for any suggestions you may have.

Again, I apologize if this is a no-brainer.
If I ask any additional questions of the SO collective consciousness in the future, I'll try to word them a bit better. Any help will be happily welcomed.

Thanks,
Neren

Comment: This doesn't make sense.  If you are trying to figure out the number of seconds on per 5 minute period, the data you listed as what you want is not going to help you much in that goal.  What happens if its resting on two periods.. started at 10:04 and ended at 10:06?  You're not going to be able to do this solely in mysql.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to transform the raw data, which is well and densely represented, write a retrieval module which reads the raw and internally transforms it to the desired representation.  I suppose it could write it back as a new table, but is there any reason  the reporting could not be generated directly from the program?

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to a "blank line" problem and can be addressed with a number table if you really must change your data.

In your db create a table called numbers and insert the numbers 0 through 9:

```
CREATE TABLE  numbers (
   num int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (num)
 );
```

The numbers table can be used for making sequences of integers which can be transformed into times. For instance, to get a sequence from 15:15 to 15:45:

```
   SELECT ADDDATE('2010-10-25 15:15:00', INTERVAL 5*`i` MINUTE) FROM (
       SELECT 10*n1.num + n2.num AS i
        FROM numbers n1 CROSS JOIN numbers n2) nums
     WHERE i <= TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF('15:45', '15:15'))/(5*60)
     ORDER BY i ASC;
```

Make the data in 2 steps. First, create the missing rows. Then update the original row to be 5 minutes long or less.